# How can I concatenate several cells with text?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I use closedXml and I want to concatenate cells which located in one row.

In column E/F/G is what I have. And in column J is that I want to see:

In addition, I want to save bold/italic format

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more complicated than I expected it to be but still relative straightforward.
Copy each `RichText` part from the three source cells to the target cell:

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(@"c:\temp.xlsx");
IXLWorksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheet(1);

foreach (IXLRow row in worksheet.RowsUsed())
{
    row.Cell("J").RichText.ClearText();
    foreach (var rt in row.Cell("E").RichText)
    {
        row.Cell("J").RichText.AddText(rt.Text).CopyFont(rt);
    }
    row.Cell("J").RichText.AddText(" ");
    foreach (var rt in row.Cell("F").RichText)
    {
        row.Cell("J").RichText.AddText(rt.Text).CopyFont(rt);
    }
    row.Cell("J").RichText.AddText(" ");
    foreach (var rt in row.Cell("G").RichText)
    {
        row.Cell("J").RichText.AddText(rt.Text).CopyFont(rt);
    }
}

wb.Save();
```

Comment: Nice, but I have a question: what does it mean 'CopyFont'? Because when I try to use this method, I have an error: 'IXLRichString' does not contain a definition for CopyFont... How I should use it?

Comment: `CopyFont` copies the font and styling (bold, italic). Which version of ClosedXML do you use?

Comment: Latest stable 0.94.2

Comment: I changed version to 0.91.0 and it works right!

Comment: `CopyFont` is an extension method. All CloseXML extension methods were made internal in version 0.93, so it should work high 0.92 or lower. If you need it in a higher version, you can copy the source code from [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Extensions.cs#L220).