# How to remove part of string and save style format

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have a cell with a content. I want to remove part of this content but with persistence style format. I tried to use function Substring(), but it doesn't save style format

For example:

My cell:

[image]

Want to see:

[image]

```
var firstDot = getCellValue.ToString().IndexOf(".");
var strWithoutBold = ws.Cell(1, 1).Value.ToString().Substring(firstDot);
```

Comment: Show your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Yeap, I added, can see

Comment: Excel is a zip file. Please change the extension to `.zip` and then unzip it. See the content of the file in notepad to see how that cell is stored and it will help in reading it with ClosedXml once you have a better idea about the XML format. Also, see what is returned in `getCellValue.Style`

Comment: can you help me with code? I am not good at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `RichText` property of the cell. First copy the the shortened text from the cell, then clear the cell and insert the remaining parts of `RichText`:

```
int firstDot = ws.Cell(1, 1).GetString().IndexOf(".");
IXLFormattedText<IXLRichText> strWithoutBold =  ws.Cell(1, 1).RichText.Substring(firstDot);
ws.Cell(1, 1).RichText.ClearText();
foreach (IXLRichString rt in strWithoutBold)
{
    ws.Cell(1, 1).RichText.AddText(rt.Text).CopyFont(rt);
}
```

PS1: when you use the index of the dot, you keep the dot (which is bold). You may need to `+1` the index.

PS2: Similar to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56885548/2610249) question, this will only work with ClosedXML versions up to 0.92. Maybe I will have a look at the library and try to make a simpler solution possibly.